# How to mirror a website on linux?

Tags: website, wget, mirroring

There is this abandoned blog witch can disappear any moment, and I want to make a browsable copy this site. The saved pages should contain correct on-page links, liked images and other files like pdf-s. It's a simple site, without any subdomains.

I tried wget bug with no luck, the links are not pointing to correct saved pages.

Comment: sounds like you want a site-ripper. I've never tried one, but check out some of these http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-web-site-ripper.htm#Quick_Selection_Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ wget -k -p -r http://chubig.net/ ./
```

works perfectly fine for me. `-k` converts links (done at the end of the download), `-p` gets all images, CSS files etc. and `-r` downloads recursively (but stays on this domain).

Comment: Is there a way to tell wget to rate limit? I would be weary of doing this if the site had a lot of content (like a forum).

Comment: `$ wget --help | grep rate`. IOW, yes.

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. I don't know about the PDF-s though, I can't try now.

Comment: If they are linked to from the website and are in the same domain, they will also be downloaded. `-p` is only necessary as, strictly speaking, CSS files and images are included rather than linked to, i.e. you use `<img src=` etc. to refer to them rather than `<a href=`, hence the ‘special’ treatment.